# How to get table header in append function?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, append

I want table header in append function.

my code till now which is showing number of rows with no header.

```
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a><table><tr><td width='200px'>" + item.label + +"</td>" + "<td width='110px'>" + item.val.split('~')[6] + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.val.split('~')[4] + "</td></tr></table></a>").appendTo(ul);
};
```